# UWP targeting listview item template property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i'm trying to make my App Design responsive.
i have ListView that have a dataTemplate with defined property:

```
            <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind manager.recentVideos}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:VideoItem" >
                           <Image Width="200"
                            Source="{x:Bind TileImage}" Margin="-10,0,-10,5"
                               ></Image>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I'm trying to change Image Width with VisualStateTrigers...
so i need to Target Setter to this property somehow....
Someone please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualStateTriggers are not supported inside DataTemplates. Just use a `UserControl` as your `DataTemplate` as is suggested in this:

[AdaptiveTrigger and DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088500/adaptivetrigger-and-datatemplate)