# VisualState is not applied to listbox ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, listbox, win-universal-app

I want to use the VisualStateManager to change the appearance of my listbox items. I created a simplified example. When the listbox or listbox items got only space for width = 500 it should set for example the background to Beige otherwise to Green.

I tried the following and some other variations but neither of them worked. Has anyone a idea how to fix this?

```
  <ListBox Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBoxItem>asdfasf</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>fasf</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>fasf</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>asdsf</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>aasf</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="visualStateGroup" >
                            <VisualState>
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="a" />
                                    <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Beige" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState>
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="b" />
                                    <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Green" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl.Content>
                        <Border x:Name="border" >
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="PathTextBlock" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=None}}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ContentControl.Content>
                </ContentControl>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I tried to adopt:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32092547/740651

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I find to do this is to create a `UserControl` of your `DataTemplate` code. So something like this

```
<UserControl x:class="MyListBoxControl">
   <Grid>
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="visualStateGroup" >
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="a" />
                                <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Beige" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="b" />
                                <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Green" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>    
                <Border x:Name="border" >
                        <TextBlock  x:Name="PathTextBlock" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=None}}" />
                    </Border>
              </Grid>
          </UserControl>
```

and then add to your ListBox ItemTemplate. The Visual States will then work accordingly. Note you will need to create a reference to where your UserControls are stored at the top of your page something like `xmlns:myUserControls="[location of your controls]"`

```
 <ListBox Grid.Column="0">
    <ListBoxItem>asdfasf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>fasf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>fasf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>asdsf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>aasf</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <myUserControls:MyListBoxControl />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Sry, this isn't working for me. Visualstate trigger seems not to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don’t manipulate the ListBox's item directly, the common way is adding the items to the `ObservableCollection` and set `ItemSource` property of `ListBox` to bind to the `ObservableCollection`.

If you use the `ItemSource`, you can use the `UserControl` like @SWilko said. But it does not need to use the `RelativeSource`.

For example, I create a `Person` class, and it has a property `Name`. I use `<TextBlock x:Name="PathTextBlock" Text="{Binding name}" />` replace  `<TextBlock  x:Name="PathTextBlock" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=None}}" />`.

If you want to add the ListBox’s item directly, and use the `VisualStateManager` to change the appearance of the `ListBox` items. You can edit the `ItemContainerStyle`.

To modify the template of `ListBoxItem`, we can select the `ListBox` in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Additional Templates**"→ "**Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)**" → "**Edit a Copy...**".

You can create a `VisualStateGroup` into the `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>`.

For example:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        ...
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="a" />
                <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Beige" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState>
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="PathTextBlock.Text" Value="b" />
                <Setter Target="border.Background" Value="Green" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And you can edit the `ContentPresenter`like:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <Border Name="border">
        <TextBlock Name="PathTextBlock"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</ContentPresenter>
```

By the way, you set the `MinWindowWidth` property to 500 of AdaptiveTrigger, the effect will not obvious. You can set it to 600.