# VisualStateManager does not hide control in UWP when width gets small

Tags: c#, resize, uwp, visibility, visualstatemanager

I have used the VisualStateManager to hide (collapse) an image control in a UWP app before, so I know it works. But in this one example (below), it does not. I cannot figure out why the big image (called imgCarDetail) does not disappear and reappear as I stretch the page wider and narrower. I think it might be related to the data binding, but I cannot see why that would effect it.

Any suggestions are welcome.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="StackoverflowExample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:StackoverflowExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:StackoverflowExample.Classes"
SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged"
Loaded="Page_Loaded"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <!-- Adjust controls on the page based on the size of the screen -->
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="vsSmallPhone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="10" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <!--<Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="12" />-->
                    <Setter Target="imgCarDetail.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="vsPhone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="18" />
                    <Setter Target="imgCarDetail.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="vsTablet">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Target="imgCarDetail.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="vsDesktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="32" />
                    <Setter Target="imgCarDetail.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid Name="tblPage" Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" x:Name="RowOne" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" x:Name="RowTwo" />
            <RowDefinition Height="165" x:Name="RowThree" />
            <RowDefinition Height="308" x:Name="RowFour" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="LabelPageSize" Text="size_here" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" />

        <!-- List of all of the car makers -->
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView Name="lvwMaster" ItemsSource="{x:Bind colAllCarMakers}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="lvwMaster_ItemClick">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Manufacturer">
                        <TextBlock Name="lblManufacturerName" FontSize="32" Text="{x:Bind Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- List of the cars built by the selected car maker -->
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="2">
            <GridView Name="grdAllCars" ItemsSource="{x:Bind colAllCars}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="grdAllCars_ItemClick" Margin="5,5,5,10" >
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Car">
                        <Image Name="imgCarThumbnail" Source="{x:Bind CarImage}" Width="100" Height="149"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Car details for a selected Car -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="tblCarDetails" Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Name="imgCarDetail" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Height="298"/>

            <TextBlock Name="lblCarDetailID" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="car_id"/>
            <TextBlock Name="lblCarDetailName" FontSize="32" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,10,10" Text="Car name" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using StackoverflowExample.Classes;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace StackoverflowExample {
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> colAllCarMakers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Car> colAllCars { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        colAllCarMakers = new ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>();
        colAllCars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    }

    private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
        LabelPageSize.Text = "W/H: " + this.ActualWidth.ToString() + "/" + this.ActualHeight.ToString();
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        await CarManager.GetManufacturers(colAllCarMakers);

        lvwMaster.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Manufacturer xSelectedManufacturer = (Manufacturer)lvwMaster.SelectedItem;
        DisplayAllCarsForTheSelectedManufacturer(xSelectedManufacturer);

        SelectFirstCarInList();
    }

    private void lvwMaster_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
        Manufacturer xSelectedManufacturer = (Manufacturer)e.ClickedItem;
        DisplayAllCarsForTheSelectedManufacturer(xSelectedManufacturer);

        SelectFirstCarInList();
    }

    private void grdAllCars_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
        Car xSelectedCar = (Car)e.ClickedItem;
        DisplayDetailsAboutTheSelectedCar(xSelectedCar);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this function to select a Car in the list, and then display the details about the Car.
    /// </summary>
    public void SelectFirstCarInList() {
        try {
            grdAllCars.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Car xSelectedCar = (Car)grdAllCars.SelectedItem;
            DisplayDetailsAboutTheSelectedCar(xSelectedCar);
        } catch (Exception) {
            //
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this function to display all of the Cars in a particular Manufacturer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xSelectedManufacturer">The Manufacturer that you want to display all of the Cars in that Manufacturer.</param>
    public void DisplayAllCarsForTheSelectedManufacturer(Manufacturer xSelectedManufacturer) {
        try {
            colAllCars.Clear();
            foreach (Car xOneCar in xSelectedManufacturer.Cars) {
                colAllCars.Add(xOneCar);
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            //
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this function to display additional details about a Car that was selected from the list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xSelectedCar">The Car that you want to display additional details about in the lower pane of the page.</param>
    public void DisplayDetailsAboutTheSelectedCar(Car xSelectedCar) {
        try {
            // Display what we know about the selected Car
            imgCarDetail.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + xSelectedCar.CarImage));
            lblCarDetailID.Text = xSelectedCar.CarID + "";
            lblCarDetailName.Text = xSelectedCar.Model;
        } catch (Exception) {
            //
        } 
    }

}
}
```

This might seem like a lot of code, but I want to give you everything you need to run and test the app, so here is the additional code you'll need to make it work.

Car.cs

```
namespace StackoverflowExample.Classes {
public class Car {
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string CarImage {
        get { return string.Format("Assets/Cars/{0}.jpg", CarID); }
    }
}
}
```

Manufacturer.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackoverflowExample.Classes {
public class Manufacturer {
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Manufacturer() {
        this.Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}
}
```

CarManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackoverflowExample.Classes {
public class CarManager {

    public static async Task GetManufacturers(ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> colCarMakers) {
        try {
            Manufacturer makerAudi = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 10, Name = "Audi" };
            makerAudi.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 111, Model = "A3" });
            makerAudi.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 112, Model = "A4" });
            makerAudi.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 113, Model = "A5" });

            Manufacturer makerFord = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 11, Name = "Ford" };
            makerFord.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 114, Model = "Focus" });
            makerFord.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 115, Model = "Mustang" });
            makerFord.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 116, Model = "Bronco" });

            Manufacturer makerVW = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 12, Name = "Volkswagen" };
            makerVW.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 117, Model = "Golf" });
            makerVW.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 118, Model = "Jetta" });
            makerVW.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 119, Model = "Beetle" });

            Manufacturer makerTesla = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 13, Name = "Tesla" };
            makerTesla.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 120, Model = "Model 3" });
            makerTesla.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 121, Model = "Model S" });
            makerTesla.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 122, Model = "Model X" });

            Manufacturer makerHyundai = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 14, Name = "Hyundai" };
            makerHyundai.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 123, Model = "Accent" });
            makerHyundai.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 124, Model = "Elantra" });
            makerHyundai.Cars.Add(new Car { CarID = 125, Model = "Sonata" });

            Manufacturer makerMINI = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 15, Name = "MINI" };
            Manufacturer makerChevrolet = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 16, Name = "Chevrolet" };
            Manufacturer makerBMW = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 17, Name = "BMW" };
            Manufacturer makerChrysler = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 18, Name = "Chrysler" };
            Manufacturer makerLexus = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 19, Name = "Lexus" };
            Manufacturer makerMercedes = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 20, Name = "Mercedes" };
            Manufacturer makerPorsche = new Manufacturer { ManufacturerID = 21, Name = "Porsche" };

            colCarMakers.Add(makerAudi);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerFord);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerVW);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerTesla);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerHyundai);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerMINI);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerChevrolet);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerBMW);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerChrysler);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerLexus);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerMercedes);
            colCarMakers.Add(makerPorsche);
        } catch (Exception) {
            //
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the very first line in each of your *Setters*:

```xml
<Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="18" />
```

breaks the working of all *Setters*. This is because you are trying to access the control that is inside the *DataTemplate* - which of the items you would like to change? One, Two, or all of them - I suppose that all, but program doesn't know that.

To make your code work you will need to do two things - throw out the mentioned line from all of your setters in MainPage - this should make the *AdaptiveTrigger* working. Then to change `lblManufacturerName.FontSize` you will have to modify the *DataTemplate* to work with the trigger. Following [Justin XL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32092547/2681948) you will have to wrap it in *UserControl* (or other *Control* with `Content`). As I've tested, something like this should work:

```xml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView Name="lvwMaster" ItemsSource="{x:Bind colAllCarMakers}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="lvwMaster_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Manufacturer">
                <UserControl>
                    <Border>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualState x:Name="vsSmallPhone">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="10" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="12" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="vsPhone">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="18" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="vsTablet">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="24" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="vsDesktop">
                                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024" />
                                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="lblManufacturerName.FontSize" Value="32" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBlock Name="lblManufacturerName" FontSize="32" Text="{x:Bind Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Border>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you Romasz. It wasn't throwing an error, so I had no reason to suspect it was causing a problem.